# I need to know if i can get GPS coordinates from a .tab file with node js

Tags: gps, tab

I have .tab file which contain  Definition Table and metadata with "\MapInfo\TableID" 
I am working on a project and they told me that I have to use that file to get the map coordinates. But i couldn't find documentation to help me for that .
is that really possible?

---

[image]

this is the example of the tab i file i have

Comment: can we see examples of the tab file? what GIS software are you using?

Comment: there is a **'file.csv'** that contains the lat/lng you require. please update your question with your 'answer'